# Filter by object unique id

Tags: ios, swift

Okay so in my app I have people who are attending an event. Of those people who are attending an event some of them maybe on my friends list. Each user has a unique user id that identifies them. Im trying to do things in a swifty way and use the filter function but I am having a little trouble. Im trying to figure out how I would filter out users who are attending an event that aren't my friends so that I only get a list of my friends that are attending.

```
   @objc func filterUsers(){
        UserService.following { (friends) in
            guard let users = self.users else {
                return
            }


            self.results = users.filter { friends.contains($0) }
        }

    }
```

This is what I have so far and it isn't returning anything because if you comapare the objects nothing will be the same. I ultimately want to compare by uid so, Im wondering if it is possible to filter with two paramters so I can just compare both using the shorthand $0.uid and $1.uid ? If not can anyone help me out with some syntax to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `contains(where:)` instead of `contains(_:)`. Here is an example:

```
struct User{
    var uid : Int
}

let users = [User(uid:1),User(uid:2),User(uid:3),User(uid:4),User(uid:5)]
let friends = [users[0],users[2],users[4],User(uid: 6),User(uid: 7)]

let results = users.filter{ (user) -> Bool in
    return friends.contains(where:{$0.uid == user.uid})
}
```